# Скролл в Windows и Linux

Tags: linux, windows, прокрутка

Как в Windows сделать так, чтоб к какому окошку мышку подводишь - то и проскроливается, как в Linux, чтоб не надо было в то окошко сначала мышкой тыкнуть, и только после этого проскроливать.

Comment: в 200х-ых я ещё на винду ставил драйвер на мышку, который добавлял буфер обмена на среднюю кнопку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Применить сниппет

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop] 
"MouseWheelRouting"=dword:00000003
```

Или если Windows 10, то в настройках **Устройства->Мышь и сенсорная панель** переключить ползунок **Прокручивать в неактивных окнах**

Сниппет проверял, работает точно в Windows 8.1 и 10. Насчет 7 надо смотреть, должно тоже работать

Comment: Значит решайте с помощью утилитки наподобие KatMouse, но аналогов вроде достаточно, можно подобрать

Comment: Еще как вариант неплохая по отзывам WizMouse